# DMIDecode showing higher maximum RAM value than OEM

Tags: memory

I am upgrading my laptop, and after consulting the user manual, it states the maximum ram capacity is 2GB, but according to `$ dmidecode -t 16`, the maximum I can get is 4GB, so, can I trust dmidecode over the oem? And would it support 4GB, or just max out at 2GB and have the remainder as hardware reserved?

```
# dmidecode 2.9
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x1000, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 4 GB
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Number Of Devices: 2
```

Comment: Maybe the chips handle 4GiB, but there is no space on the motherboard?

Comment: well, there are two slots, and I have found 2x2GB chips, so it will fit, but it's whether the system can support it

Comment: More RAM than specified as *known working and tested* by the OEM often works, but not always. Most of the times it fails is when higher density RAM chips (the chips on the SoDIMM, not the total capacity) are used of if there simple are not enough copper address lines to the SoDIMM sockets.

Comment: Isn't it this case: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ ?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz not really, but would have been the perfect answer to another question i asked around this time on high memory usage on linux